# Linq query embeds a subquery when I don't think it's necessary -- optimization?

Tags: performance, linq

I have a linq query that I'm trying to speed up.

```
                List<WorkloadDTO> workload = _context.vwData.AsNoTracking()
                    .Join(_context.AppUsers, vis => vis.AssignedToAppUserID, us => us.AppUserId, 
                        (vis, us) => new
                        {
                            vis.GroupID, 
                            vis.FacilityIsActive,
                            vis.ClientIsActive,
                            vis.GroupIsActive,
                            vis.IsClosedAccount,
                            vis.AssignedToAppUserID,
                            us.AppUserName,
                            us.AppUserDisplayName
                        }
                    )
                    .Where(i => i.GroupID == 1 && i.FacilityIsActive && i.ClientIsActive && i.GroupIsActive && !i.IsClosedAccount)
                    .GroupBy(g => new { g.AssignedToAppUserID, g.AppUserName, g.AppUserDisplayName },
                        (key, group) => new {
                            AssignedToAppUserID = key.AssignedToAppUserID,
                            AssignedTo = key.AppUserName,
                            AssignedDisplayName = key.AppUserDisplayName,
                            Count = group.Count()
                        })
                    .Select(s => new WorkloadDTO
                    {
                        AppUserId = s.AssignedToAppUserID,
                        UserName = s.AssignedTo,
                        DisplayName = s.AssignedDisplayName, 
                        Count = s.Count
                    }).Distinct().OrderBy(o => o.UserName).ToList();
```

It generates the following query:

```
SELECT [t].[AppUserId], [t].[UserName], [t].[DisplayName], [t].[Count]
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT [v].[AssignedToAppUserID] AS [AppUserId], [a].[AppUserName] AS [UserName], [a].[AppUserDisplayName] AS [DisplayName], COUNT(*) AS [Count]
    FROM [vwData] AS [v]
    INNER JOIN [AppUser] AS [a] ON [v].[AssignedToAppUserID] = [a].[AppUserId]
    WHERE (((([v].[GroupID] = 1) AND ([v].[FacilityIsActive] = CAST(1 AS bit))) AND ([v].[ClientIsActive] = CAST(1 AS bit))) AND ([v].[GroupIsActive] = CAST(1 AS bit))) AND ([v].[IsClosedAccount] = CAST(0 AS bit))
    GROUP BY [v].[AssignedToAppUserID], [a].[AppUserName], [a].[AppUserDisplayName]
) AS [t]
ORDER BY [t].[UserName]
```

It seems to me that the nesting selects are not necessary.  I'm looking for suggestions on how to write the linq query so that it instead results in:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT [v].[AssignedToAppUserID] AS [AppUserId], [a].[AppUserName] AS [UserName], [a].[AppUserDisplayName] AS [DisplayName], COUNT(*) AS [Count]
    FROM [vwData] AS [v]
    INNER JOIN [AppUser] AS [a] ON [v].[AssignedToAppUserID] = [a].[AppUserId]
    WHERE (((([v].[GroupID] = 1) AND ([v].[FacilityIsActive] = CAST(1 AS bit))) AND ([v].[ClientIsActive] = CAST(1 AS bit))) AND ([v].[GroupIsActive] = CAST(1 AS bit))) AND ([v].[IsClosedAccount] = CAST(0 AS bit))
    GROUP BY [v].[AssignedToAppUserID], [a].[AppUserName], [a].[AppUserDisplayName]
    ORDER BY [a].[AppUserName]
```

Comment: What LINQ are you using: LINQ to Objects / SQL / EF 6.x / EF Core 2.0 / 2.1 / 3.x / 5.x / 6.x? What database provider?

Comment: I don’t  think you can force EF to generate exact same query. Do you have performance problems with generated SQL?

Comment: @NetMage this is EF Core 6.x, database-first scaffolded into the solution. DB is SQL Server.  When I removed the outer query from that generated nested query, I saw better performance. I'm trying to tune everything that I can in this application.